# user-specific data replication

Tags: permissions

I am currently using an admin user with full data access and getUpdated() and getDeleted() to replicate Salesforce.com data with a local database.

Now I tried to replicate only the data a specific user with limited permissions can see (e.g. the user has only access to his own leads, account). It works well to initiate the replication, but if I remove leads from the user, getDeleted() does not replicate the fact that the user can no longer access the object. Hence, the replication is not valid anymore.

How can I replicate data for a specific user so that even object changes get recognized that are not based on the object having changed, but the user's access permissions having changed?

Answer (score 1):

I see only the following options:

- replace the full local database with a new copy of SF each time
  or
- keep track of all recordIds replicated in the last run, and delete any records that are not part of a new run